# How was/is playback of music handled on consoles such as the NES, Master System, Gameboy, etc?

Tags: software-engineering, music

So, I deliberately left out the SNES because AFAIK the music subsystem is basically entirely self-contained. However, on systems like the NES and Gameboy, while there are sound chips, there isn't any sort of dedicated sound CPU.

My question is how one reliably plays back music without putting too much of a burden on the CPU? Timing is clearly very critical: music won't sound right if the notes aren't played at exact intervals. Naively, one might just continually update the registers of the sound chip. However, this leaves no time for programming game logic! You could plan to update the registers every cycle in the main loop, but then any interrupts triggered would throw everything off.

I haven't been able to find any information on this, despite there seeming to be a clear conceptual gap! So basically, how does a game like say, Super Mario Bros on the NES manage to play back music consistently and reliably, regardless of what is happening on screen?

Comment: What made you think that NES doesn't have dedicated audio chip? But anyway this question seems offtopic to me.

Comment: No, the NES does have a dedicated sound chip, just no dedicated audio *processor*. With a SNES, you load a program into the SPC-7000, and then communicate with it later on, but the sound CPU itself handles the low-level stuff of updating the sound chip registers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about historical trivia.

Comment: Normally those kind of hardwares had either a synth chip, so you do not "compute the waveform" in the CPU and send to a DAC (would be super CPU consuming), but you just code the registers in the audio chips and let the chip generate the waveform. On the other side, more "natural sounding" systems, used "samples" for playing back notes. In those cases, usually you program the sound-chip from the CPU and the sound-chip gets the waveform from RAM via DMA (not "dynamic" synth by the CPU, would be too consuming, but replay pre-loaded samples). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got you. But then that made you think that CPU alone is not enough to handle sound? It's rather primitive, well, it's definetely not a PC-speaker, but not too far from it. 22 mapped register WORDs is a *complete* configuration of a NES APU. It also includes basic caps for cycles and frequency generation, so it's not all on CPU every cycle.

But generally, I guess, this was just a hardware limit which was unawoidable for developers, they have no other options but to reserve CPU power for sound processing.